# How do i creqate low resolution image

Tags: android

I am making 1 android app where am capturing the image.I have used Media store also. Average image size is 128 KB.and I want it till 65-75 KB.

Answer (score 0):

size of the file is always a trade of with quality - there are multiple ways to do so:

- increase compression rate
- decrease colors
- decrease size

Comment: how to do this in android.I have done  bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);.But how to decrease color and size and compress rate?